# "Do you want to keep this document 'Untitled NN'?" dialog obscures the actual image when quitting Prev

Tags: preview

*Behind* the dialog shown in the screenshot lies the actual (smallish) picture. So we can not determine what is actually being closed without saving.  The dialog can not be moved afaict.  How do folks handle this?

[image]

Comment: Press Cancel, then decide whether you want to keep it before closing the window again.

Comment: Presumably you know what it is anyway, since you closed the window it was in.

Comment: @calum_b Fancy leaving that as an answer?

Comment: @MarcWilson i don't follow there - no I don't know what it is

Comment: @calum_b That might be  a long process when there are 23 images to go through.  Instead I'd just give up on this and manually walk through the images .  It's strange there's no way to relocate the dialog